# Java GUI Knights tour wrong algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I am a beginner to java and new to data structures and algorithms. I am trying to implement the Knights tour to GUI with java swing. There are no errors in the code, but I think I made a mistake in applying the algorithm. So I made an 8x8 board made up of buttons and lets the user pick the initial move of the knight. At first, the knight moves correctly but when it does not have any available moves, it goes randomly to another box. I couldn't find the problems since I new to recursion and backtracking. here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Chess implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[8][8];
    JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();
    final int BOARDSIZE = 8;
    final int NUM_OF_MOVES = BOARDSIZE;
    private int startx;
    private int starty;
    private int delay = 10000;
    private int stepCount;
    public int [] xMoves = {2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2};
    public int [] yMoves = {1,2,2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1};

    public Chess(){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Chess Algo");
        frame.setSize(800, 800);

        boardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));

        for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<buttons.length;j++){
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setFocusable(false);
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                boardPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
            
        }
        frame.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<buttons.length;j++){
                if(e.getSource() == buttons[i][j]){
                    stepCount++;
                    buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                    buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    buttons[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(stepCount));;
                    startx = j;
                    starty = i;
                    stepCount++;
                    start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<buttons.length;j++){
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        solve(stepCount, startx, starty);
    }

    public boolean solve(int stepCount, int x, int y){
        if(stepCount == BOARDSIZE * BOARDSIZE){
            return true;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_MOVES;i++){
            int nextX = x + xMoves[i];
            int nextY = y + yMoves[i];

            if( isStepValid(nextX,nextY)){
                new javax.swing.Timer(delay, this).start();
                moveNext(nextX, nextY);

                if( solve(stepCount+1, nextX, nextY))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void moveNext(int x, int y){
        buttons[y][x].setBackground(Color.green);
        buttons[y][x].setText(Integer.toString(stepCount));;
        buttons[y][x].doClick();
        stepCount++;
    }
    public boolean isStepValid(int x, int y){
        if( x < 0 || x >= BOARDSIZE) return false;
        if( y < 0 || y >= BOARDSIZE) return false;
        if(!(buttons[y][x].getText().equals(""))) return false;

        if(buttons[y][x].getText().equals("")) ;
          return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Chess();
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used about 10 start squares and every time the algorithm worked well. Which choice causes a problem?

Comment: the problem is in the last few steps, when you reach 50+ steps, the knight moves incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem correctly:

I think your "exit strategy" is wrong. So you never tell recursion to stop recursion. I've redesigned the relevant section a bit. Of course, there is still room for improvement and optimization.

```
public boolean solve(int stepCount, int x, int y){
        System.out.println(stepCount + " stepCount: " + x + " | " + y);
        if(stepCount == BOARDSIZE * BOARDSIZE){
            return false;
        }
        int nextX = x;
        int nextY = y;
        
        boolean valid = false;
        
        for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_MOVES;i++){
            nextX = x + xMoves[i];
            nextY = y + yMoves[i];

            if( isStepValid(nextX,nextY)){
                new javax.swing.Timer(delay, this).start();
                moveNext(nextX, nextY);
                valid = true;
                break;
                //if( solve(stepCount+1, nextX, nextY))
                //    return true;
            }
        }
        if(valid){
            return solve(stepCount+1, nextX, nextY);
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution stops without visiting all squares, and so it does not provide a solution to the Knight's Tour Problem.

Comment: Yes that's right. Then this path is wrong and he must take another. This is not a solution to the entire problem. If the knight cannot go any further, another path must be chosen. This means that all other steps that led to this situation must also be reversed.